# How to position tabbar on the left side in .net MAUI Shell?

Tags: maui

Is this possible to do with shell? i have spent the last two days searching but have not come with anything. All i saw was the same question being asked on Microsoft community 2.5 years ago but it has no answer.

This is what im trying to. please see the link below.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/98622998-c3ad-4c96-96cc-1d4d289433db/i-want-to-set-positionleft-of-tabbar-of-shell-in-tablet-android-please-help?forum=xamarinforms

Will have i to do some custom UI to achieve this in MAUI shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i found the answer. It was in the weather twenty one sample app all along. I guess the answer was so obvious that no one asks about it.

Link to the file in the sample app:
https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne/blob/main/src/WeatherTwentyOne/App.xaml